# search result replace abbreviation to text

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have a search form that looks up information in a SQL DB, the data has a column of abbreviations for a product type.  I want to upload the data with the abbreviations and use the PHP to expand the text in the search results.

For example
PF = Prefinished

Can this be done or will this slow down the search exponentially?

```
if ($producttype == "PF") {
    $producttype == "Prefinished"
    }
else{
  // Else
    }
```

Comment: Depending on the abbreviations, this could easily return unexpected results probably - for example the search `upfront` would return `uprefinishedront` unless the search is specifically just the abbreviation.

Comment: Presumably you have a linked table providing the expanded values, so it would be more efficient to extract the necessary values from the database.

Comment: I am using an array to fetch the data and was not sure if I could force the change just on one variable.

Comment: I am not sure about your response. You would use a table join to extract whatever fields you need from the related tables, the rows of values could still then be used with one of PHP's methods that fill an array.

Comment: `=` is used for assignment, `==` for comparison. Presumably you want the second thing to be an assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to put these conversions into a table where you can map between code and name, and possibly vice-versa if necessary.

Then you can `JOIN` against this table to get expansions. For small tables this cost is nominal, you really won't feel it in benchmarks.

```
CREATE TABLE product_types (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  code VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  label VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `index_product_types_on_code` (`code`)
);
```

Then populate this accordingly so you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM products
  LEFT JOIN product_types ON product_types.code=products.producttype
```

If that's a problem, though, and this data changes infrequently, you can load it in to your application layer as an associative array and map them in PHP.